# My eclipse has become corrupt?

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse has suddenly started showing errors in all projects. All the projects which suddenly started showing errors. I reinstalled eclipse and java but problem persisted. please help

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import android.widget.BaseAdapter is never used Services.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 14 Java Problem
The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated  LeaderboardActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 92 Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated LeaderboardActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 98 Java Problem
The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated  LeaderboardActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 97 Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated LeaderboardActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 106    Java Problem
The import java.util.List is never used Services.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 4  Java Problem
The import android.view.Menu is never used  Services.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 9  Java Problem
The import android.widget.Button is never used  Main.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 24 Java Problem
The import android.view.View.OnClickListener is never used  Main.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 21 Java Problem
The method isNetworkAvailable() from the type Main is never used locally    Main.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 171    Java Problem
The import android.widget.Toast is never used   Main.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 26 Java Problem
The method setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState) from the type WebSettings is deprecated  CompanyWebsite.java /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 27 Java Problem
The import android.view.Menu is never used  FAQsActivity.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 8  Java Problem
The import android.view.ViewGroup is never used GameEndActivity.java    /GujaratiQuiz/src/com/androidmedics/astronomyquiz   line 9  Java Problem
The import android.view.ViewGroup is never used MainActivity.java   /GujaratiQuiz/src/com/androidmedics/astronomyquiz   line 16 Java Problem
The import android.widget.ImageButton is never used MainActivity.java   /GujaratiQuiz/src/com/androidmedics/astronomyquiz   line 18 Java Problem
The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated  ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 66 Java Problem
The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated  ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 77 Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 81 Java Problem
The import android.graphics.Color is never used Contact_us.java /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 7  Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 89 Java Problem
The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated  ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 123    Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated GamePlayActivity.java   /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 120    Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated GamePlayActivity.java   /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 130    Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 127    Java Problem
The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated  ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 132    Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 147    Java Problem
The import android.view.Menu is never used  SimpleWebViewActivity.java  /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 7  Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 169    Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 175    Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated ProfileActivity.java    /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 193    Java Problem
The type Gallery.LayoutParams is deprecated GalleryActivity.java    /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 108    Java Problem
The import android.net.Uri is never used    Main.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 18 Java Problem
The type Gallery is deprecated  GalleryActivity.java    /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 108    Java Problem
The constructor Gallery.LayoutParams(int, int) is deprecated    GalleryActivity.java    /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 108    Java Problem
The import android.view.Menu is never used  PatientEducationActivity.java   /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 8  Java Problem
The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated GamePlayActivity.java   /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 109    Java Problem
The import android.text.format.Time is never used   GetGameActivity.java    /GujaratiQuiz/src/com/androidmedics/astronomyquiz   line 22 Java Problem
The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated  GamePlayActivity.java   /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 118    Java Problem
The import android.graphics.Paint is never used GetGameActivity.java    /GujaratiQuiz/src/com/androidmedics/astronomyquiz   line 16 Java Problem
The method dismissDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated  GamePlayActivity.java   /ScoreloopCoreDemoSimple/src/com/scoreloop/client/android/core/demo/simple  line 108    Java Problem
The type Gallery is deprecated  GalleryActivity.java    /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 55 Java Problem
The type Gallery is deprecated  GalleryActivity.java    /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 55 Java Problem
The type Gallery is deprecated  GalleryActivity.java    /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 13 Java Problem
The import android.widget.Toast is never used   GalleryActivity.java    /Company Profile/src/com/white/aashudentalclinic    line 15 Java Problem
```

When i make apk out of this they are crashing.Actually all this imports are used in the project, also project works well on ther pc.

Comment: Check to see if your ADK and target version are what you expect them to be; have you alo tried cleaning up all projects?

Comment: yes sir already cleaned and checked but still same warnings in all projects